# Browser's Network Tab is not Recording New GET/POST requests but new data are loading

Tags: python, web-scraping, browser, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the https://mojodice.com website.

So, I checked the network tab. But after the website is loaded I am unable to find the data in the NETWORK TAB of chrome.

Also, New games(lose/win) are being added every minute. But no get/post request in network tab.

screenshot:
[NetWork Tab of browser is not showing anything but new data are being loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufoie.png)

Why is this happening?
How can find which 'link' is being used to load win/lose data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to mark the "Preserve log" box so that everything that gets recorded does not get deleted.

Comment: I have tried marking on "Preserve log" but no results. Nothing is showing on network tab, still new data are loading.

Comment: I think it may be protected then, so the website does not allow you to record it. I tested it myself and it did not work for me too.